# Wordpress website won't open menu pages

Tags: wordpress, mobile

I have been struggling with this for more than a week and didn't find anything or anyone who could answer so I am trying my luck here.

I made the following website: http://1mikesflooring.ca

When I open any of the menus/gallery, instead of opening the page, a blank window with an activity indicator appears and nothing else happens. The only way to open a new page is opening it on a new tab.

Also, the mobile version is not working either.

Here's a screenshot of how it looks like:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/f43ve1ttwuwe3ii/Screenshot%202015-11-12%2000.28.27.png?dl=0

If anyone has seen this before and know how to fix it, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide some specific links or directions to links that don't work? Everything appears to be working where I'm looking, although I can't find any gallery. I'm on OSX using Chrome

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?